# How to display alt text for an image in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

The image with invalid source displays an alternate text in Firefox but not in chrome unless the width of an image is adjusted.

```
  <img height="90" width="90"
    src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif"
    alt="Image Not Found"/>
```

How to display the alt text for an image?

Comment: Which version of chrome are you using? Because, according to http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=16734 this should have been fixed.

Comment: This still seems to be a problem in Chrome 29 (2+ years on)! Unless the width of the element is wide enough to show the alt text in its entirety, on one line, then the alt text does not show!?

Comment: ...and the element needs to have some height. At least 44px in my tests.

Comment: You shouldn't use the alt tag to say "image not found" because it is used by screen readers for blind and partially-sighted people. See [this](http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/web-accessibility/image-alt-text.shtml) for tips.

Comment: I also got the same issue in Firefox 45.8.0 - and title="hover text here" solves it nicely.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

If I'm correct, this is a bug in webkit (according to [this](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5566)). I'm not sure if there is much you can do, sorry for the weak answer.

There is, however, a work around which you can use. If you add the **`title`** attribute to your image (e.g. `title="Image Not Found"`) it'll work.

Comment: @Prisoner, <img src="pic.png" />, not <img href="" />. Width and height make no difference. Also, src shouldn't be empty or omitted, in practice, it never is (and that's the only reason why your example worked).

Comment: The image height and width shouldn't make a difference.  (But some browsers are weird.)  A better example than the one in the comment above:  http://jsfiddle.net/o8syw0bp/

Answer (score 24):

You can use the `title` attribute.

```
<img height="90" width="90"
src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif"
alt="Google Images" title="Google Images" />
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes it's an issue in webkit and also reported in chromium: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=773
It's there since 2008... and still not fixed!!

I'm using a piece of javacsript and jQuery to make my way around this.

```
function showAlt(){$(this).replaceWith(this.alt)};
function addShowAlt(selector){$(selector).error(showAlt).attr("src", $(selector).src)};
addShowAlt("img");
```

If you only want one some images:

```
addShowAlt("#myImgID");
```

Comment: I don't know why I'm still having this problem in Chrome, you'd think that this would be a major thing to fix, but your code worked (once wrapped in a domready block.  So thanks.

Comment: can you provide your solution in plunker or jfiddle please.

Comment: This bug appears to be still existing in 2016! Can your javascript solution be "turned" into a Chrome extension or a boomarklet for instant-activation?

Answer (score 4):

**Use title attribute instead of alt**

```
<img
  height="90"
  width="90"
  src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg12.gif"
  title="Image Not Found"
/>
```

Comment: please explain it why Use title attribute instead of alt

Comment: we have to use both title and alt for browser compatibility as different browsers consider different attribute in this case title/alt

Comment: @Harsh yeah u r right.actually i was testing on Google chrome so i post code according to that.but we have to use both for multiple browser.

Comment: I also go through an article.I think it would be best to understand the difference between  alt and title attribute.[DIFFERENCE BETWEEN  ALT AND TITLE ATTRIBUTE](http://www.worcestershirewebdesign.co.uk/blog/why-doesnt-alt-text-show-up-in-firefox/)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple workaround in jQuery. You can implement it as a user script to apply it to every page you view.

```
$(function () {
  $('img').live('mouseover', function () {
    var img = $(this); // cache query
    if (img.title) {
      return;
    }
    img.attr('title', img.attr('alt'));
  });
});
```

<del>I have also implemented this as a Chrome extension called [alt](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/alt2title/hgaoapmlflfdaefemmidddbgmgajoejh). Because it uses `jQuery.live`, it works with dynamically loaded content, too.</del> *I have retired this extension and removed it from the Chrome store.*

Answer (score 1):

Various browsers (mis)handle this in various ways.  Using title (an old IE 'standard') isn't particularly appropriate, since the title attribute is a mouseover effect.  The jQuery solution above (Alexis) seems on the right track, but I don't think the 'error' occurs at a point where it could be caught.  I've had success by replacing at the src with itself, and then catching the error:

```
$('img').each(function()
{
    $(this).error(function()
    {
        $(this).replaceWith(this.alt);
    }).attr('src',$(this).prop('src'));
});
```

This, as in the Alexis contribution, has the benefit of removing the missing img image.

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer 7 (and earlier) displays the value of the alt attribute as a tooltip, when mousing over the image. This is NOT the correct behavior, according to the HTML specification. The title attribute should be used instead. Source: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_alt.asp

Answer (score 1):

To display the Alt text of missing images, we have to add a style like this. I think, there is no need to add extra javascript for this.

```
.Your_Image_Class_Name {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

It's work for me. Enjoy!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can put title attribute to  tag.I hope it will work.

```
<img src="smiley.gif" title="Smiley face" width="42" height="42">
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be entered in the javascript console to replace empty titles with alt text (if available) for images on a single page:

```js
[...document.getElementsByTagName('img')].forEach((x) => {
  if(x.getAttribute('alt') && !x.getAttribute('title')){
    x.setAttribute('title',x.getAttribute('alt'));}})
```

It doesn't require JQuery.

Answer (score -2):

I use this, it works with php...

```
<span><?php
if (file_exists("image/".$data['img_name'])) {
  ?>
  <img src="image/<?php echo $data['img_name']; ?>" width="100" height="100">
  <?php
}else{
  echo "Image Not Found";
}>?
</span>
```

Essentially what the code is doing, is checking for the *File*.  The `$data` variable will be used with our array then actually make the desired change.  If it isn't found, it will throw an Exception.