# img alt attribute seems not to work in google chorme

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have a problem  in the following line of code of HTML

```
<img src="smile.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42">
```

if the smile.gif image does not exist on the server , Google Chorme does not show me the   the alt attribute as does firefox, but an empty image icon

Can you help me?

Comment: Please check [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386570/how-to-display-alt-text-for-an-image-in-chrome)

Comment: Did you search at all? It's a webkit bug that has existed for half a decade, and it doesn't look like they're going to fix it.

Comment: Friend there any way to remove the ugly icon and display only the title. Javascript might work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use title attribute for chrome

Comment: thanks friend. Title working but I want remove the empty image

Comment: Friend there any way to remove the ugly icon and display only the title

Comment: you need to check condition if image exist or not by any scripting language