# How to dynamically set alternate text to images in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to add alternate text to images dynamically in angularjs.
I tried this.

```
alt={{dynamicText}}.
```

Simply setting like this doesnt seem to work.

Comment: What your answer suggests is that what you were actually looking for was "title text" rather than "alt text" (as in, have the browser pop some text above the mouse hover on a specific element). The `alt` tag is used primarily for accessibility purposes (and should be used more often to help that purpose) - perhaps you can update your question & answer to reflect that a little better?

Answer (score 6):

You just have to use "" just like in normal html. So:

```
alt="{{dynamicText}}"
```

Comment: Sorry there was typo in the question. this is what I tried initially. But not working.

Comment: Could you add the complete link html to your question?

Answer (score 5):

It was the problem of Chrome browser. As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386570/how-to-display-alt-text-for-an-image-in-chrome), putting it like this solves the issue.

```
title="{{dynamicText}}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use []: `[alt]="dynamicText"`