# Alt text not showing echo using wp_get_attachment

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata, custom-post-type, alt

Alt text not showing...

```
    $images = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'vdw_gallery_id', true);



                if( $images ): ?>
                    <ul>
                        <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>

                                <li>
                            <a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_url($image, 'large');  ?>">
                                <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_url($image, 'medium'); ?>" alt="Alter TEXT" />
                            </a>
                                </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                <?php endif; ?>
```

I try many ways but not getting how to echo alter text I create meta field for gallery.

I know wp_get_attachment_image_src this will show everything but I only need to echo "alt" text within loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display alt text for an image in chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386570/how-to-display-alt-text-for-an-image-in-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the title tag and the alt tag and possibly give it a width and height, check out this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8925364/7862006

```
<img alt="alternative text" title="alternative text" style="min-width: 50px; min-height: 25px;" src="..........
```